# MySQL to Sqlite

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I hope you can help me with my Database Problem:

I have a mysql database with several tables and i want to build an android app out of it. I'm trying to convert this database for days now and I cant find a working solution. I already tried the shell scripts which you find via google but none of them works: it seems like table creation is failing at some point. Errors are:

```
"no such collation sequence: utf8_unicode_ci" and "no such table:xxx".
```

I guess there is a problem with table creation. What can i do?!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which script did you use to get this error?

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of tools to do that, as you did not mentioned whcih script caused the Error you get its hard to say why you get this Error , but check [this list](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki/wiki?p=ConverterTools) of conversion  tools/scripts. I guess [dataPro](http://www.vive.net/products/datapro.htm) is specially interesting but its not Free.